# Salesforce1 javascript method navigateToSObject(recordId,view) not changing tab

Tags: salesforce1-app

I'm using the javascript method
navigateToSObject(recordId,view) detailed on page 185 of http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/salesforce1/salesforce1_guide.pdf

example usage is:

```
sforce.one.navigateToSObject('a01i00000085XZGAA2','related');

sforce.one.navigateToSObject('a01i00000085XZGAA2','chatter');
```

When this javascript is executed on a VF page launched by sf1 I am taken to the correct record, but with the default 'detail' tab open. Anybody hit this issue as well? Or find a work around? :)

I am able to reproduce this in one/one.app and the actual app.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: I gave it a try, too without success. I've escalated this to R&D.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a mismatch between the Salesforce1 docs and current Salesforce1 functionality. The "navigate to a specific slide" functionality is scheduled for Summer '14 (safe harbor!).

Comment: Looks like this fell out of Summer '14 and the docs still aren't updated :( Anybody have luck navigating to a specific slide yet?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, @metadaddy is right , I have used navigation : sforce.one.navigateToSObject(recordId,view) where you can navigate to an specific record , and it is working.  I would like to add that this navigation is working at this moment only with the first parameter :sforce.one.navigateToSObject(recordId) you can use the second one : view , but it won't send you to the selected view ( "chatter" or "detail" or "related" list views). As I commented I've been using this navigation and is working but no with the second parameter and I've been in contact with SF support and they confirmed to me that this call-navigation will be fully implemented for Summer '14(safe harbor), meanwhile we can use it knowing that it will always redirect you to the "detail" view.