# How to navigate to the account I'm currently checking in Salesfore1?

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-apps

I am in my custom VF page (called by a Lightning app) and I would like to be able from there to go to the account standard page. I do already this to go to the home page via an easy Javascript function, I would like to do the same for the Salesforce1 account page. Any ideas? Context/code below:

```
<apex:page controller="Account_Controller_2" docType="html-5.0">
<script>
    function ExitButton() 
    {
        sforce.one.navigateToURL("/home/home.jsp");
    }
</script>
<script>
    function GoToAccountButton()
    {
        sforce.one.navigateToSObject(!!!WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE?!!!);
    }
</script>
[...]<apex:outputField value="{!account.Name}"/>
```

[...]

```
//"GoToAcc" BUTTON --> NOT WORKING
 <input type="button" value="GoToAcc" onclick="GoToAccountButton()" id="btnGoToAccount"/>
//"EXIT" BUTTON --> WORKING
 <input type="button" value="Exit" onclick="ExitButton()" id="btnExit"/>
```

[...]

Thanks in advance for your help!
Cheers, Francesco

Comment: Your Controller probably doesn't have a get method on account. See Ruslan Vekua's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/salesforce1_dev_jsapi_sforce_one.htm

Take a look at this 
[Salesforce1 javascript method navigateToSObject(recordId,view) not changing tab](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22246/salesforce1-javascript-method-navigatetosobjectrecordid-view-not-changing-tab) question as well.

**Controller:**
[image: controller]

**VF page:**
[image: VF page]

**Account details page after calling the GoToAccountButton function:**
[image: Account details page]

Comment: Yes I already found both the function description page and the question page. They weren't enough though, seen that thing are still not working (see my reply to above comment). Thanks a lot anyway! Francesco

Comment: It works fine for me. I will edit my answer and put the screenshots.

Comment: Use {!account.Id} instead of {!Account.Id} and take a look at the edited answer how to query account details and assign them to the account variable.

Comment: Yes, it works! Ihad forgotten the '' notation in my previous attempts. Thanks a lot Ruslan! PS: my javascript level is 0, that will probably explain my struggling. Cheers, Francesco

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sforce.one.navigateToSObject("{!Account.Id}");
```

`navigateToSObject(​recordId​[, view])` method takes 2 arguments, the recordID, in your case the AccountID and an optional view method. So if you want you can specify to which tab it should navigate.

> The possible values are as follows.
>
> - detail: the record detail slide
> - chatter: the Chatter slide
> - related: the view of related slide

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/salesforce1_dev_jsapi_sforce_one.htm

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply.
    <script>
        function ExitButton() 
        {
            sforce.one.navigateToURL("/home/home.jsp");
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        function GoToAccountButton()
        {
            sforce.one.navigateToSObject({!account.Id});
        }
</script>

I had already tried to insert {!Account.Id} but nothing happened. ExitButton() works instead.. Any ideas?
Cheers, Francesco

Comment: How about just {!account} instead of {!account.id}?

Comment: it worked with Account.Id. Error was in the notation: correct line is (FYI):
sforce.one.navigateToSObject('{!account.Id}');
Thanks a lot for your help, Francesco